# Using "gdal_translate" from .TIF to .JPG how to set background to white?

Tags: cmd, gdal

I tried using the following line:

```
gdal_translate -of jpeg -a_nodata 0 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 c:\myfolder\mytif.tif c:\myfolder\myNewtif.jpg
```

This produces the image with wanted specs, but turns the background to black  (transparency?), eventhough the original has white. Can I accomplish a white background with just gdal_translate?

File dump of a file with mask: 
https://filebin.net/f15v63to2x3cc4z0

File dump of a file with no a mask: https://filebin.net/kc940hqotcoeny0w

> gdalinfo output of a Tif that produces white background as expected:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test.tif
Size is 4799, 3196
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=300
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=300
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 3196.0)
Upper Right ( 4799.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 4799.0, 3196.0)
Center      ( 2399.5, 1598.0)
Band 1 Block=4799x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=4799x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=4799x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

> Tif that produces black background:

```
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 100011_1.tif
Size is 1640, 2401
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2020:01:13 12:29:55
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop 21.0 (Windows)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=300
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=300
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 2401.0)
Upper Right ( 1640.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 1640.0, 2401.0)
Center      (  820.0, 1200.5)
Band 1 Block=1640x39 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=1640x39 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=1640x39 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=1640x39 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Also of the following images that have black background after translate, gdal produces this warning "`Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag: Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored`"

Comment: Hi! Could you share your tif file so that we can reproduce your problem more easily?

Comment: Absolutely. Sorry for using image dump site. The file was too large for stackoverflow.

Comment: The file that you have shared downloads as a PNG from the image dump site, so I cannot reproduce your problem (the image still has a white background after `gdal_translate`).
Could you print the results of the `gdalinfo` command on your TIF file?

Comment: Added gdalinfo output.

Comment: To make thing even more confusing now the current "test.tif" converts with white background, but not all images. I am trying to convert over 2000 tifs, of which some produce black background.

Comment: You could try comparing the gdalinfo of files whose conversion "works" and files whose conversion "doesn't work". Other than that, I don't see the cause of your issue

Comment: Added more information on the subject.

Comment: Additional question: Is it possible to provide resolution sizes in gdal_translate?

Comment: Yes you can give the target resolution of the output image, as described in the documentation: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal-translate-tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that you have shared on filebin contains an "alpha" mask, as you can see in the output of `gdalinfo`. The mask of this file says that the background is masked, while the rest of the image is not.

If you display the tiff with the default Ubuntu viewer, for example, you can see that the background pixels are masked out (they appear as a checker board)
[image: masked tiff]

If you inspect the raster data, you also see that the underlying pixels from the background are black, not white. That is why `gdal_translate` generates a jpeg with black pixels in the background, it is because they really are black (but masked out) in the original tiff file.

If you absolutely want the background to be white, you can do so with a few lines of Python using the [`rasterio`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) library for example, by explicitly setting the masked pixels to white:

```py
import rasterio

with rasterio.open("101679_1.tif") as src:
    arr = src.read(masked=True)

    # Convert all masked values to white
    arr[arr.mask] = 255

    # Write to jpeg file
    profile = src.profile
    profile["count"] = 3
    profile["driver"] = "jpeg"
    with rasterio.open("test.jpeg", "w", **profile) as dst:
        dst.write(arr[:3])
```

This should give the following jpeg file:

[image: jpeg with white background]

The code snippet I have included above will also work on TIF files which already have a white background, because the `arr[arr.mask] = 255` line will not do anything if the file contains no mask.
To process a directory full of `.tif` files, you can do:

```py
from glob import glob
import rasterio

for tif in glob("*.tif"):
    with rasterio.open(tif) as src:
        arr = src.read(masked=True)

        # Convert all masked values to white
        arr[arr.mask] = 255

        # Write to jpeg file
        profile = src.profile
        profile["count"] = 3
        profile["driver"] = "jpeg"
        with rasterio.open(tif.replace(".tif", ".jpeg"), "w", **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(arr[:3])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. guampi. This is the correct answer to my problem as described.

Comment: #guampi can I ask you to prove and example to run this on a folder of files as I have over 2000 files? Even more efficient would be to run in only on files with files that have the background masked.

Comment: If you send me the link to a file that does not have the background masked, I can adapt my code to handle both cases.

Comment: Added filebin link to a file with no mask.

Comment: My snippet will also work on files that do not have a masked background. I've edited my answer to show you how you could run it on a folder with lots of files.

Comment: hi @guampi I want to convert my .tiff or .tif file to transparent background jpeg/png image. I want to convert my .tiff/.tif image very similar to the first image which you have for making background white. I want to do this using python. Can you please help in that. I gave tried various library like matplotlib, opencv, Pillow. All of them are background to white not transparent. Can you help in that or suggest some article.